# FullCalendar Delete Events and ReAdd them

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm having a problem with my jquery fullcalendar. 
Above the calendar, I have dropdown that does filtering of events in the calendar.

So, what I try to do is remove all events and assign new events based on the dropdown. The view gets duplicated everytime. 
You must have seen this before, but before you advise me to read a link, please know that:
1. I am using javascript function to retrieve the view source.
2. I am not using any json feed or php (I just can't).
3. Because of #2 I can't use eventsrouce or google feed.

I am relying on js heavily to do the events filtering (I just have to). Here is the code I tried and the code for my calendar. 
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ events: generateFiltered() });
generatefiltered is a js function that retursn data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        editable: true,
        disableDragging: true,

        // Event handlers
        events: events(),
        eventClick: eventClick,
        dayClick: dayClick
    });
});
```

the initial load uses this line:
 events: events() which is also another javascript that returns data.

The only thing I can think of now is to drop the calendar (via finding its div) and then recreating it, which I am trying to avoid.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeEvents to delete all events from calendar and then addEventSource for adding new array of events

Comment: I've ended up removing the calendar like I said at the end of my post and recreating it all again. Maybe using the method you suggested, would have been better. 
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
...
eventSources: [eventFetchFunction], //don't call this function here!
...

eventFetchFunction = (start, end, timezone, callback) => {
   const myCreatedEvents = []
   //do whatever you want here to generate or fetch events and add them to this array

   callback(myCreatedEvents)
}
```

Whenever you have to recreate the events, just call

```
.fullCalendar( ‘refetchEvents’ )
```

Then the function will be retriggered